# jQuery Ajax call inside another Ajax call issue

Tags: jquery

I have ASP.NET MVC application. In one view I use jQuery Ajax call inside another Ajax call. It looks as following:

```
$.ajax({
        url: this._getHostName()+'Search/OrderStep3',
        success: function (data) {
        ...

        html.push('<li><a href="#">A</a></p>');
        html.push('<li><a href="#">B</a></p>');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Search/GetHelloWorld',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: "GET",
            crossDomain: "true", 
            async: false,  
            success: function (data1) {
                alert(data1);
                html.push('<li><a href="#">' + data1 + '</a></p>');
            }
        });

        html.push('</ul>');
```

As you can see I just want to add new element to the list. But, that element is not added. Alert inside inner Ajax call displays proper data, but it's not added after that.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think async order just doesn't work for JSONP. Try closing your list inside second ajax call.

Comment: I've put entire list inside second Ajax call and it doesn't work.

Comment: if you do console.log(html) inside 2nd call what you get?

Comment: There are all elements except that one inside second Ajax call.